# Proving ${n \choose k}^{-1} = (n+1)\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\mathsf dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, combinatorics, definite-integrals, binomial-theorem

Title says it all, I've tried to find the indefinite integral of the right side, got some sort of weird series and got stuck:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n-k {n-k \choose i}\cdot{(-1)i\over k+1+i}$$

Comment: I'm comfused. If $k\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $x^k(1-x)^n-k\leq0$  for $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Something's wrong in the given equality in the title, I think.

Comment: I'd assume the integrand is supposed to be $x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ (that works for a few values of $n$ and $k$ that I tried, so I edited. Someone fix it if I'm wrong :)

Comment: If you understand the Beta function, this is quite simple. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: There must be a glitch in the Matrix, because I'm experiencing a [deja-vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_June_10#Basic_Demonstration_Required)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see using the definition that
$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}\binom{n-2}{k-2} = \dotsb $$
Since $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ for this to make sense, we can iterate this until we get down to $\binom{n-k}{0}=1$. Therefore we have to prove that the integral satisfies the same recurrence relation (upside-down) and boundary condition. This is easy to do with the right integration by parts:
$$ \begin{align*}
&(n+1)\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^{n-k} \, dx \\
&= (n+1)\left[ -\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right)^k \right]_0^1 + \int_0^1 (1-x)^{n+1} \left( k x^{k-1}(1-x)^{-k} + kx^k(1-x)^{-k-1} \right) \, dx \\
&= 0 - k \int_0^1 x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n+1} (1-x)^{-k-1} (1-x+x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{k}{n} \left( n \int_0^1 x^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-k} \, dx \right)
\end{align*}, $$
so the integral satisfies the same recurrence as $\binom{n}{k}^{-1}$. All we have to do now is check the boundary conditon, which is just
$$ (n+1)\int_0^1 x^{k-k} (1-x)^{n-k+k} \, dx = 1, $$
so the result follows.

It's one of those lovely results where you choose the right integration by parts to start with, and then everything just works. And even better, you don't ever need $n$ to be an integer.